# How to change direction of the Y axis in xChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, d3.js

Does anyone know how to change the order / direction of the Y axis in xChart? I have played around with the var opts:

```
    var opts = {
  "dataFormatX": function (x) { return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d').parse(x); },
  "tickFormatX": function (x) { return d3.time.format('%B')(x); },

  "dataFormatY": function (y) { return y; },
  "tickFormatY": function (y) { return d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("right"); }
```

However, nothing i have tried has worked and there seems to be little documentation on it. There must be an option to choose "ASC" or "DESC" somewhere? (0 - 10 or 10 - 0).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you trie reversing the values given to `domain()` and `range()` of `yScale`?

Comment: xCharts does not have this ability.

Comment: Ah, i see. Thanks Paul, that's a shame as it's a nice piece of kit in terms of styling. I've looked at just using D3 on its own but looks rather long winded and styling by default is pretty poor.